# Can Caleb write an article about framing questions?

Tags: discussion

Can Caleb write an article about framing questions? I fail to receive the benefit that I am supposed to receive by reading the Help Center.

Comment: I've migrated this to meta so you can expand on what you're looking for. There are dozens of posts here on scoping. Try [meta-tag:scope]

Comment: have you visited http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Here's a list a template questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac)

Comment: Or even [meta-tag:scope], @waxeagle.

Comment: @TRiG good catch.

Comment: To help you understand a few things about this community. Caleb, Wax Eagle, El'endia and Mason Wheeler are moderators. They are community members just like us, but we elected them to have superuser permissions. Their opinions are not necessarily more important that anyone else's and it certainly never trumps what the community at large says. If a meta post is highly upvoted, then you can trust that the community agrees with it, on the whole, no matter who wrote it.

Comment: [Here's another meta post that links to a lot of the really good meta posts](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/newcomers-be-patient-you-will-get-there-if-you-follow-our-direction-keep-tryi)

Comment: Also, [you can search all posts by a particular user.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A30+good+question) Caleb is user id 30. You can tell from the url for his profile. Your user id is 9253.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already an excellent guide to how to ask questions at: [Writing the Perfect Question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/697/writing-the-perfect-question?rq=1)
(click on the highlight)

You might try also reviewing the questions in meta that is where I learned a lot even though I am still relatively ignorant of many of the nuances of the site.

I have even resorted to asking someone else to rewrite my question when I was new to the site. I might add that I got more down votes and question cancellations at first than I did up votes. So don't be discouraged and take the time to look at how people with a lot of reps ask. by clicking on the screen name in orange you can look at their profile and use them as a guide. The questions they have asked with results are listed on their profile and you can learn a lot there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Cecil your awesome.

Answer (score 3):

I already have. See here:

[What makes a good focused question?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/30)

You might also be interested in other posts on meta such as those tagged [faq+questions](/questions/tagged/faq%2bquestions).

Comment: Yay! Thanks Caleb, I hope to read it soon.